# SQLite INTEGER(11) column behaving strangely

Tags: sql, sqlite, dataset

So this is a SQLite database and the column `map_id` in table `locations` is of type `INTEGER(11)`. I try to update all instances where `map_id` is `0` or `-1` to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE locations SET map_id = NULL WHERE map_id = 0 OR map_id = -1
```

I add this query to my strongly-typed DataSet in a `QueriesTableAdapter`. I run this query and then fill my DataSet table `locations` with the underlying database data, hoping that I won't see any `0` or `-1` in `map_id` column. Booo! I have some. I run the UPDATE query again and check the number of affected rows; it is zero. So no rows were affected by the UPDATE query, meaning there are no rows with `map_id` `0` or `-1`. Yet I see them in the fetched `DataTable`. What's going on here?

Comment: I'd lay money that you've got some caching going on.  Try pulling a slightly different data-set into your DataTable.  Perhaps `SELECT map_id, COUNT(*) FROM locations GROUP BY map_id`?  Or perhaps your `NULL` rows are being represented in the DataTable as `0`?

Comment: @MatBailie: mmm... I can confirm that it is not the second case. I can already see NULL values in the DataTable in addition to 0s.

Comment: Ridiculous. `UPDATE locations SET map_id = NULL WHERE map_id=''` affects some rows and now I don't get any 0s in the DataTable. Go figure.

Comment: And you're positive it's an INTEGER column?  Freaky horrible.

Comment: @MatBailie: I rechecked it and it is `INTEGER(11)` in SQLite. The problem is deeper than I had imagined. My assumption is that this is happening because of the fact that SQLite is typeless. So one can store anything in a column regardless of the column definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [SQLite is typeless](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html), one can store anything in any column and it won't complain. So what was happening in my case was that someone had stored empty string in an `INTEGER` type column. That's why my query was not updating those rows, even if they appeared similar to NULL cells. I have now added a check for empty string in my `UPDATE` query. Hope this helps someone down the road.